# Media query works on firefox but chrome picks up wrong resolution / query

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, media-queries

Honestly getting sick of these queries as they seem to never work out for me.
I used firefox while coding the website but then realized i never checked chrome to see how it operates there so decided to check it out and its picking up the wrong res (Firefox picks up the right resolution and query but chrome picks up wrong).

My computer res: 1280 x 768 - landscape.

My media query that works on firefox (Should work on chrome too?):

```
/*! Desktop 768 - 1280 x 768 */

@media only screen 
  and (max-height: 768px) 
  and (max-width: 1280px) 
  and (orientation: landscape) 
{
    #cover-art
    {
    height:330px;
    width:330px
    }

    #time-knob .btn, #volume-knob .btn
    {
     width: 100px;
    }
}
```

The query chrome picks up is (I made it for my Imac 24):

```
/*! Imac 24*/

@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1920px) 
  and (orientation: landscape) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) 
{
    .knobs
    {
        margin-top:20%;
    }

    .btn-group, .btn-group-vertical
    {
        padding-top: 15px;
    }

    #time-knob .btn, #volume-knob .btn
    {
        width: 100px;
    }

    .mainplayback
    {
        margin-top:20%;
    }

    .swiper-button-next, .swiper-button-prev
    {
        top: 65%;
    }

    #home-blocks
    {
        margin-top:4%;
    }

    .empty-block, .home-block
    {
        padding: 70px 30px;
    }

    .empty-block i, .home-block i
    {
        width: 70px;
        height: 50px;
        font-size: 70px;
    }

    .empty-block h3, .home-block h3
    {
        font-size: 34px;
    }

    body
    {
        font-size:19px;
    }

    #cover-art
    {
        height:500px;
        width:500px
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Non tested just yet but i edited the imac query to go with height and width:

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-height: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1920px) 
  and (orientation: landscape) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) 
{
```

Now lets the chrome read my proper query! Now i need to test if the Imac can read its query with this change but should work ;)